# Two otherwise identical functions (one uses Template Pattern, other doesn't)

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

```
#include <iostream>

void doSomething (int x) {std::cout << "Do something with " << x << std::endl;}

struct Base {
    virtual int foo() const {return 5;}
    virtual int goo() const {return 6;}
    virtual int hoo() const {return 7;}
    void noTemplatePattern() const {
        // Code A
        if (Base::foo() < 6) {
            // Code B
        }
        doSomething (Base::goo());
        // Code C
        if (Base::hoo() > 10) {
            // Code D
        }
    }
    void templatePattern() const {
        // Code A
        if (foo() < 6) {
            // Code B
        }
        doSomething (goo());
        // Code C
        if (hoo() > 10) {
            // Code D
        }
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual int foo() const override {return 12;}
    virtual int goo() const override {return 13;}
    virtual int hoo() const override {return 14;}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.noTemplatePattern();
    d.templatePattern();
}
```

How best to avoid repeating the codes contained in Code A, Code B, Code C, Code D, etc... other than creating helper functions for each?  Is there a more generic way?  I have functions that are identical except one uses the Template Pattern, and the other doesn't.  The body of code between the virtual functions are identical.  If I define a helper function for each identical part, it gets really messy, and there will be too many of them too.

In case you want more clarification, here is a snippet of my production code illustrating this.  `SpellCaster` is derived from `LivingBeing`, and `LivingBeing::cannotAttackLongRange(int)` is overridden by `SpellCaster::cannotAttackLongRange(int)`.

```
inline std::set<LivingBeingProxy*> LivingBeing::unattackableTargets() const {
    std::set<LivingBeingProxy*> nonTargets;
    if (isCharmed()) {
        for (auto it = std::next(getStatesList(CHARM_SPELL).begin(), 1);  it != getStatesList(CHARM_SPELL).end();  ++it)
            nonTargets.emplace (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CharmedStateBase>(*it)->getCharmer());
    }
    for (LivingBeingProxy* x : getLocation()->allBeingsAlive()) {
        if ( (x->heightAboveGround() > damageInflictor(0)->getReach()) && !canFly()
    && LivingBeing::cannotAttackLongRange(distanceBetween(this, x->getActual()))) //*** virtual method here!
            {nonTargets.emplace(x);  continue;}
        if ( (x->heightAboveGround()) < 0 && (x->getTerrain() == InWater) && !canSwim() )
            {nonTargets.emplace(x);  continue;}
    }
    // ...
    return nonTargets;
}

inline std::set<LivingBeingProxy*> LivingBeing::unattackableTargetsIncludingBySpells() const {
    std::set<LivingBeingProxy*> nonTargets;
    if (isCharmed()) {
        for (auto it = std::next(getStatesList(CHARM_SPELL).begin(), 1);  it != getStatesList(CHARM_SPELL).end();  ++it)
            nonTargets.emplace (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<CharmedStateBase>(*it)->getCharmer());
    }
    for (LivingBeingProxy* x : getLocation()->allBeingsAlive()) {
        if ( (x->heightAboveGround() > damageInflictor(0)->getReach()) && !canFly()
    && cannotAttackLongRange (distanceBetween(this, x->getActual()))) //*** virtual method here!
            {nonTargets.emplace(x);  continue;}
        if ( (x->heightAboveGround()) < 0 && (x->getTerrain() == InWater) && !canSwim() )
            {nonTargets.emplace(x);  continue;}
    }
    // ...
    return nonTargets;
}
```

`LivingBeing::unattackableTargets()` computes all enemies that are not attackable by ordinary weapons, while `LivingBeing::unattackableTargetsIncludingBySpells()` computes all enemies that are not attackable by ordinary weapons and spells.  A `SpellCaster` will want to call the first when attacking with an ordinary weapon, and will want to call the second when attacking with a spell.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more about your actual use case please? As is, it sounds a bit like asking for a XY-problem for me.

Comment: I have functions that are identical except one uses the Template Pattern, and the other doesn't.  The body of code between the virtual functions are identical.  If I define a helper function for each identical part, it gets really messy, and there will be too many of them too.

Comment: _I have functions that are identical ..._ They aren't _identical_ of course.

Comment: I still don't get what should be a good use case for this. Sounds like you have found a serious design flaw with your code at hands. Don't try to fix the symptoms, refactor instead.

Comment: I added some of my production code in my question to illustrate it.

Comment: Looks like the [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) would be more useful, to solve this, instead of having two seperate functions for the case.

Comment: But when I put the above into the Strategy Pattern, the separate execute() overrides still contain the identical sections of code.  It's still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With template and CRTP, if appropriate, you may do something like:

```
template <typename T, typename D>
void helper(const D& base)
 {
    // Code A
    if (base.T::foo() < 6) {
        // Code B
    }
    doSomething (base.T::goo());
    // Code C
    if (base.T::hoo() > 10) {
        // Code D
    }
}

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual int foo() const {return 5;}
    virtual int goo() const {return 6;}
    virtual int hoo() const {return 7;}

    void noTemplatePattern() const
    {
        // use Base::foo, Base::goo and Base::hoo
        helper<Base>(*this);
    }
#if 0
    virtual void templatePattern() const = 0;
#endif
};

template <typename Derived>
struct BaseImpl : Base {
    template <typename Derived>
    void BaseImpl<Derived>::templatePattern() const {
        // use Derived::foo, Derived::goo and Derived::hoo
        helper<Derived>(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));
    }
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/kAATlX)

Comment: Yes!  This is the type of solution I was looking for.  Though it doesn't allow `someTemplatePattern()`, where some places use the Base functions and some do not, like my solution allows (by accident), but it is the most elegant to construct `noTemplatePattern()` without the huge amount of parameters that are in my solution.

Comment: @prestokeys: All current solutions have their drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If `templatePattern` / `noTemplatePattern` are long and complicated and `boo`, `goo` and `hoo` are simple, you could do the following:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int foo(bool = false) const {return 5;}
    virtual int goo(bool = false) const {return 6;}
    virtual int hoo(bool = false) const {return 7;}
    void Pattern(bool base) const {
        // Code A
        if (foo(base) < 6) {
            // Code B
        }
        doSomething (goo(base));
        // Code C
        if (hoo(base) > 10) {
            // Code D
        }
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int foo(bool base = false) const override {return base ? Base::foo() : 12;}
    int goo(bool base = false) const override {return base ? Base::goo() : 13;}
    int hoo(bool base = false) const override {return base ? Base::hoo() : 14;}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.Pattern(true);  // d.noTemplatePattern();
    d.Pattern(false); // d.templatePattern();
}
```

Not exactly elegant, but might work in a particular situation.

NB: If you use `override` keyword, you don't need to repeat `virtual` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

One solution with Tag dispatching (but require more code for `foo`, `goo`, `hoo`)

```
struct Base {
    virtual int foo() const {return foo(std::false_type());}
    virtual int goo() const {return goo(std::false_type());}
    virtual int hoo() const {return hoo(std::false_type());}

    void noTemplatePattern() const { doIt (std::false_type()); }
    void templatePattern() const { doIt (std::true_type()); }

private:
    template <typename T>
    void doIt (T t) const {
        // Code A
        if (foo(t) < 6) {
            // Code B
        }
        doSomething (goo(t));
        // Code C
        if (hoo(t) > 10) {
            // Code D
        }
    }
    // tag dispatching between virtual call and Base::call
    int foo(std::false_type) const {return 5;}
    int goo(std::false_type) const {return 6;}
    int hoo(std::false_type) const {return 7;}
    int foo(std::true_type) const {return foo();}
    int goo(std::true_type) const {return goo();}
    int hoo(std::true_type) const {return hoo();}
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Tl4jEZ)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is one solution I thought of, but though it works I don't know if it is considered any good (need some opinions).  But at least all repeated code is avoided, and thus any changes to those parts needs only be made once:

```
#include <iostream>

void doSomething (int x) {std::cout << "Do something with " << x << std::endl;}

struct Base {
    virtual int foo() const {return fooBase();}
    virtual int goo() const {return gooBase();}
    virtual int hoo() const {return hooBase();}
    virtual void voidFunction() const {voidFunctionBase();}

    void noTemplatePattern() const {
        doIt (&Base::fooBase, &Base::gooBase, &Base::hooBase, &Base::voidFunctionBase);
    }
    void templatePattern() const {
        doIt (&Base::foo, &Base::goo, &Base::hoo, &Base::voidFunction);
    }

private:
    void doIt (int(Base::*a)()const, int(Base::*b)()const, int(Base::*c)()const,
        void(Base::*d)()const) const {
        // Code A
        if ((this->*a)() < 6) {
            // Code B
        }
        doSomething((this->*b)());
        // Code C
        if ((this->*c)() > 10) {
            // Code D
        }
        (this->*d)();
        // Code E
    }
    int fooBase() const {return 5;}
    int gooBase() const {return 6;}
    int hooBase() const {return 7;}
    void voidFunctionBase() const {std::cout << "Base::voidFunction() called.\n";}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual int foo() const override {return 12;}
    virtual int goo() const override {return 13;}
    virtual int hoo() const override {return 14;}
    virtual void voidFunction() const override {std::cout << "Derived::voidFunction() called.\n";}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.noTemplatePattern();
    d.templatePattern();
}
```

Output:

```
Do something with 6
Base::voidFunction() called.

Do something with 13
Derived::voidFunction() called.
```

Opinions?  A better solution?

Comment: what do you think about my answer?

Comment: It's a fully working solution.  It does cost a bit of performance time with the if checks though, but fully operational otherwise and avoids any repeated code.  The client code will be something like:  `Derived d;  d.Pattern(true);  d.Pattern(false);`

Comment: You got it, sir. I s'pose I should add the usage example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility, if applicable, is to slice your object:

```
void noTemplatePattern() const {
    // copy only Base part (slicing). Require that Base is constructible
    Base(*this).templatePattern();
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ciEL0c)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy, no-nonsense solution for this: Just replace the two functions by one which takes a parameter `bool includeSpells`. Then you can just check for this parameter in the function and execute the appropriate function call. The rest of the function remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes, that is Innocent Bystander's solution.  Costs a bit of performance time if there are many checks, but a valid solution.

Comment: In a function using `std::set::emplace()`, an additional boolean check is virtually free. Trust me, your conditions are not your performance bottleneck. A single boolean check is already dwarfed by the creation of the `std::set` return object.

Comment: You may replace the boolean runtime check by compile time check with tag dispatching. Answer added.

Comment: The difference between my solution and InnocentBystander's one is, that I would add the flag argument directly to `unattackableTargets()`, and select the call directly within that function. I would't use a wrapper for `cannotAttackLongRange()` to get the selection right.